# No se muestra llama correctamente al toString de la clase padre

Tags: c#

**Tengo esta lógica en C#.**

**Siendo "Universo" una clase padre y "Superheroe" una clase hija.**

**Por consola, me muestra:**

Superhéroe: Batman

Poder: Multimillonario

¿ Héroe ?: True

Arma: puños

Cantidad Ediciones: 20

Primera Publicación: 30 Marzo de 1939

Universo: Batman

**Cuando lo correcto seria:**

Superhéroe: Batman

Poder: Multimillonario

¿ Héroe ?: True

Arma: puños

Cantidad Ediciones: 20

Primera Publicación: 30 Marzo de 1939

Universo: DC

**Este es mi codigo:**

```
internal class Universo
    {
        //clase padre
        private String nombre;
        public Universo(){

        }

        public Universo(String nombre){
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }
        public string GetNombre(){ return this.nombre; }
        public void SetNombre(string nombre) { this.nombre = nombre; }
     
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "\n Universo: "+ this.nombre;
        }
    }
```

---

```
internal class Superheroe:Universo
    {
        private String poder;
        private Boolean heroe=false;
        private String arma;
        private int ediciones;
        private String primeraPublicacion;
        private Universo universo;

        public Superheroe()
        {

        }
        public Superheroe(String nombre) : base(nombre)
        {

        }
        public Superheroe(String nombre, String poder, Boolean heroe, String arma, int ediciones,
            String primeraPublicacion, Universo universo): base(nombre)
        {
            this.poder= poder;
            this.heroe = heroe;
            this.arma= arma;
            this.ediciones= ediciones;
            this.primeraPublicacion= primeraPublicacion;
            this.universo= universo;
            
        }

        public String GetPoder() { return this.poder; }
        public void SetPoder(String poder) { this.poder = poder; }

        public Boolean GetHeroe() { return this.heroe; }
        public void SetHeroe(Boolean heroe) { this.heroe = heroe; }

        public String GetArma() { return this.arma; }
        public void Set(String poder) { this.poder = poder; }

        public int GetEdiciones() { return this.ediciones; }
        public void SetEdiciones(int edicione) { this.ediciones = edicione; }

        public String GetPrimeraPublicacion() { return this.primeraPublicacion; }
        public void SetPrimeraPublicacion(String primeraPublicacion) { this.primeraPublicacion = primeraPublicacion; }

        public Universo GetUniverso() { return this.universo; }
        public void SetUniverso(Universo universo) { this.universo = universo; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "\n Superhéroe: " + GetNombre()
                + "\n Poder: " + this.poder
                + "\n ¿ Héroe ?: " + this.heroe
                + "\n Arma: " + this.arma
                + "\n Cantidad Ediciones: " + this.ediciones
                + "\n Primera Publicación: " + this.primeraPublicacion
                + base.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Me gustaría ver como estas creando el objeto que muestras por consola.

Comment: Por ser una única variable la que recibes al heredar, y que además estás guardando una referencia al universo al que pertenece en la instancia de superhéroe, la herencia en este caso es innecesaria. De ese modo reemplazarías `base.ToString()` por `universo.ToString()`.

Comment: Así Universo dc= New Universo("dc")

Comment: Superheroe batman = New Superheroe("Batman",  "multimillonario", true,"puños", "marzo de 1939", dc).

Answer (score 1):

Veamos el segundo constructor:

```
public Superheroe(String nombre) : base(nombre)
{
}
```

A partir de ahí ya puedes identificar por qué el nombre del universo es el mismo del superhéroe. Estás diciéndole que pase el nombre del superhéroe al constructor del universo.

Con el tercer constructor sucede exactamente lo mismo.

Solución: Sé que puede ser tentador intentar aplicar todo lo que aprendiste, pero no hacerlo no significa que esté mal. En este caso, la herencia no parece ser lo más adecuado. Así que deberías dejar de heredar `Superhéroe` de `Universo`.

La clase superhéroe quedaría así:

```
class Superheroe
{
    private string nombre = "Sin nombre";
    private string poder = "Ninguno";
    private bool heroe = false;
    private string arma = "Ninguna";
    private int ediciones = 0;
    private string primeraPublicacion = "Desconocida";
    private Universo universo = null;

    // Propiedades
    public string Nombre { get => nombre; set => nombre = value; }
    public string Poder { get => poder; set => poder = value; }
    public bool Heroe { get => heroe; set => heroe = value; }
    public string Arma { get => arma; set => arma = value; }
    public int Ediciones { get => ediciones; set => ediciones = value; }
    public string PrimeraPublicacion { get => primeraPublicacion; set => primeraPublicacion = value; }
    internal Universo Universo { get => universo; set => universo = value; }

    //  Constructores
    public Superheroe()
    {
    }

    public Superheroe(string nombre)
    {
        this.Nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Superheroe(string nombre, string poder, bool heroe, string arma,
        int ediciones, string primeraPublicacion, Universo universo)
    {
        this.Nombre = nombre;
        this.Poder = poder;
        this.Heroe = heroe;
        this.Arma = arma;
        this.Ediciones = ediciones;
        this.PrimeraPublicacion = primeraPublicacion;
        this.Universo = universo;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "\n Superhéroe: " + Nombre
            + "\n Poder: " + Poder
            + "\n ¿Héroe?: " + (Heroe ? "Si" : "No")
            + "\n Arma: " + Arma
            + "\n Cantidad Ediciones: " + Ediciones
            + "\n Primera Publicación: " + PrimeraPublicacion
            + Universo;
    }
}
```

Como puedes ver, hice varias cosas además.

- En el `ToString` aparece solo `Universo` porque llama implícitamente su método `ToString`.
- `Boolean`, `Int32`, `Single`, `Char` y `String` son clases. [`bool`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/bool), [`int`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types#characteristics-of-the-integral-types), [`float`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types#characteristics-of-the-integral-types), [`char`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char) y [`string`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types#the-string-type) son sus respectivos alias. Hay muchos más y puedes usarlos.
- En C# existe el [operador ternario](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) que funciona como un if-else. Es útil cuando quieres asignar una sola variable en función de una condición.
- En C# existen [propiedades](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/properties). Como puedes ver, tienen la forma de una variable, pero con la diferencia de que les das un cuerpo entre llaves. Se parecen mucho a unas funciones que definiste.

Esto:

```
public String GetPoder() { return this.poder; }
public void SetPoder(String poder) { this.poder = poder; }
```

Es equivalente a esto:

```
public string Poder
{
    get
    {
        return poder;
    }
    set
    {
        poder = value;
    }
}
```

Que puedes expresar de una forma más sintética:

```
public string Poder { get => poder; set => poder = value; }
```

La diferencia con las funciones está en cómo usas las propiedades.

Al ser funciones debes llamarlas, pasando el nuevo valor como parámetro en caso del setter:

```
Console.WriteLine(spiderman.GetNombre());
// Spiderman
spiderman.SetNombre("Peter Parker");
```

Mientras que a la propiedad la tratas como una variable normal:

```
Console.WriteLine(spiderman.Nombre);
// Spiderman
spiderman.Nombre = "Peter Parker";
```

---

Si pruebas tu clase:

```
var universo = new Universo("Marvel");
var superheroe = new Superheroe("Hulk", "Fuerza", true, "Puño", 1, "F", universo);
Console.WriteLine(superheroe);
```

Imprimirá en consola:

```
 Superhéroe: Hulk
 Poder: Fuerza
 ¿Héroe?: Si
 Arma: Puño
 Cantidad Ediciones: 1
 Primera Publicación: F
 Universo: Marvel
```

Como último dato, C# puede inferir tipos a las variables si las declaras con [`var`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación, ha sido de gran ayuda